# Storage size of POINT type in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial, point

I'm storing some geospatial data in an SQL database and so the obvious type to use seems to be 'POINT'. However, on closer inspection, it seems this type is using a rather large amount of data. When fetching points, each entry uses 25 bytes, many of which seem redundant and common to every item in the column. 
There are 4 bytes for some sort of ID, then 1 byte for the byte order and then another whole 4 bytes for an integer that describes the data type (it's a Point, which we know already) followed finally by two double precision coordinate values. For large databases, this seems like a waste.

Is the really how the database stores values internally? The data seems redundant and excessive and it's also not dword aligned, which I imagine can't be good for performance. Does mysql store these 25 byte records internally and only pad the data out when responding to a select query (still bad but maybe not as bad)?
If so, would two separate floats/doubles be more appropriate. Are there any other advantages to using this type?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I'm using mysql. Your answer begs another question: in terms of the data I get back when I run a 'select' statement, is there any standardisation? If I were to migrate to another database backend, would that break my code for decoding 25 byte Point types? 
In other words, is the data stored and transmitted in the same format?

Comment: On the SQL level you are not concerned whether a point uses 25, 16 or 42 bytes. You just handle a column value of type `point`. As the support for spatial features is vastly different between different database products - yes you can expect the SQL code to fail - but not because of the storage size.

Comment: Thing is, when I select point data, I get back a binary blob unless I use 'X(location) as X' etc., which isn't always convenient.  Still, good to know what's portable and what's not.